# I can't use wxpython properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I've installed Python in my VSCode (Python Version 3.8) and I want to do a project using wxPython. I've installed wxPython using:

```
pip install wxPython
```

My problem is the following: After i `import wx` in VsCode it can't find any module for my project from this library. For example:
[image]

Comment: can you please provide the output of `pip freeze > list.txt`

Comment: do you have problem to run code? If not then problem is PyCharm, not `wxpython`.

Comment: @fnet WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -xpython 4.0.7.post2 (d:\py\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-xpython'": Expected W:(abcd...)

Comment: @furas It runs but not properly, but what with PyCharm? Im not using PyCharm

Comment: @furas would you mind confirming the package list of `pip list` as well. Looks like you may need to reinstall the `wxPython` package: `pip install --upgrade -r wxPython`

Comment: sorry, all IDEs looks so similar - If code works in VSC then problem is VSC. If you have error when you run code then show it in question but I doubt if this is the problem. I would rather expect that problem is `VSC`. OR you have file `wx.py` in your folder and `import wx` loads this file instead of module `wxPython`.

Comment: @furas looks like the package name is `-xpython` rather than `wxPython` from the output of `pip freeze` provided above, would you agree? Sorry that comment above was suppose to be @idn, I tagged the wrong person.

Comment: @fnet i used pip list and i have wxPython Version 4.0.7.post2

Comment: @fnet `pip` gives me `wxPython 4.0.4` so now I update `wxPython` and I see it installs version `4.0.7.post2` (like in error) but name `-xpython` in error is strange .

Comment: Also i tried using PyCharm and it give me the following error : Collecting wx

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wx (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wx

Comment: I was thinking about two things: (1) you may have two Pythons imstalled and `pip` installed `wxPython` in one Python but VSC runs code with other Python - so it can't find `wx`. (2) Python 3.8 is very fresh version (and I will wait few months before I use it), and maybe it makes problem. I still use 3.7

Comment: @furas yeah it does appear the currently nightly is not resolving via pip freeze. Perhaps @idn you could try rolling back to a previous build, reinstalling the package after removing, and double check you do not have a script named `wx.py` in your project folder as @furas mentions. Also check your virtual env as @furas mentions and make sure you are using `pip` for python 3 (pip3) and not for python 2 - double check by typing `python --version` inside your virtual env, if you're using one.